# Manual duplex printinting Canon MX475

Tags: printing, pdf, canon

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I have the Canon MX475 printer. I want to print a document on both sides of the paper. I have installed my drivers using the tutorial from this page [Drivers_tutorial](http://blog.milsystems.de/2013/01/canon-pixma-mx715-unter-linux-ubuntu-installieren/) (in German). On the website of the printer under duplex printing it says that it is manual.

I tried the following:

- in Document Viewer -> Print -> Page Setup -> Layout -> Two-sided: Not available; I cannot select anything from the drop-down menu
- in Okular -> Print -> Options -> Duplex Printing; I have some radio buttons which I cannot select
- in Adobe Reader 9 -> I do not have any option about duplex printing
- from command line by using this command `lp -o sides=two-sided-long-edge file.pdf`

Does this mean that I cannot print on both sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way to print duplex manually using `gnome-manual-duplex`. It's in the standard repositories and works well out of the bo with certain printers. It may need manual configuration for other printers.